# Не могу создать apk игры на pygame

Tags: python, pygame, buildozer

вот код игры если нужно:

```py
import pygame
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((618, 359))

ghosts = []
bullets = []

image_path = "data/data/com.develooper.first_pygame/files/app/"

icon = pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/icon.png").convert_alpha()
bg = pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/bg.png").convert_alpha()
ghost = pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/ghost.png").convert_alpha()
bullet = pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/bullet.png").convert_alpha()

front = (pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_f1.png").convert_alpha(),
         pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_f2.png").convert_alpha(),
         pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_f3.png").convert_alpha(),
         pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_f4.png").convert_alpha())
back = (pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_b1.png").convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_b2.png").convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_b3.png").convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_b4.png").convert_alpha())
left = (pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_l1.png").convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_l2.png").convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_l3.png").convert_alpha(),
        pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_l4.png").convert_alpha())
right = (pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_r1.png").convert_alpha(),
         pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_r2.png").convert_alpha(),
         pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_r3.png").convert_alpha(),
         pygame.image.load(image_path + "images/spritesheet/spritesheet_r4.png").convert_alpha())

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

anim_count, bg_x = 0, 0
p_x, p_y = 150, 250

backk, is_jump = False, False

p_speed, jump_count, bullets_left = 5, 8, 5

gameplay = True

label = pygame.font.Font(image_path + "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf", 40)

lose = label.render("Вы проиграли", False, (193, 196, 199))
restart = label.render("Играть снова", False, (115, 132, 168))

restart_rect = restart.get_rect(topleft=(180, 200))

ghost_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ghost_timer, 2500)

pygame.display.set_caption("Игра на pygame")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

bg_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(image_path + "sounds/Windows Critical Stop.mp3")

running = True
while running:
    screen.blit(bg, (bg_x, 0))
    screen.blit(bg, (bg_x + 618, 0))

    if gameplay:
        p_rect = left[0].get_rect(topleft=(p_x, p_y))
        if ghosts:
            for ghost_cord in ghosts:
                screen.blit(ghost, ghost_cord)
                ghost_cord.x -= 10

                if p_rect.colliderect(ghost_cord):
                    print("you lose")
                    sleep(1)
                    gameplay = False

        bg_sound.play()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and p_x > 50 or keys[pygame.K_a] and p_x > 50:
            p_x -= p_speed
            screen.blit(left[anim_count], (p_x, p_y))
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and p_x < 200 or keys[pygame.K_d] and p_x < 200:
            p_x += p_speed
            screen.blit(right[anim_count], (p_x, p_y))
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
            backk = True
        else:
            if backk:
                screen.blit(back[anim_count], (p_x, p_y))
            else:
                screen.blit(front[0], (p_x, p_y))

        if not is_jump:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
                is_jump = True
        else:
            if jump_count >= -8:
                if jump_count > 0:
                    p_y -= (jump_count ** 2) / 2
                else:
                    p_y += (jump_count ** 2) / 2
                jump_count -= 1
            else:
                is_jump = False
                backk = False
                jump_count = 8

        if anim_count == 3:
            anim_count = 0
        else:
            anim_count += 1

        bg_x -= 2
        if bg_x == -618:
            bg_x = 0

        if bullets:
            for bullet_rect in bullets:
                screen.blit(bullet, (bullet_rect.x, bullet_rect.y))
                bullet_rect.x += 4
                if bullet_rect.x > 630:
                    bullets.remove(bullet_rect)
                if ghosts:
                    for ghost_rect in ghosts:
                        if bullet_rect.colliderect(ghost_rect):
                            ghosts.remove(ghost_rect)
                            bullets.remove(bullet_rect)

    else:
        screen.fill("red")
        screen.blit(lose, (180, 100))
        screen.blit(restart, restart_rect)
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if restart_rect.collidepoint(mouse) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            gameplay = True
            p_x = 150
            ghosts.clear()
            bullets.clear()
            bullets_left = 5

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == ghost_timer:
            ghosts.append(ghost.get_rect(topleft=(620, 250)))
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if gameplay and event.key == pygame.K_SLASH and bullets_left != 0:
                bullets.append(bullet.get_rect(topleft=(p_x + 30, p_y + 10)))
                bullets_left -= 1

    clock.tick(10)
```

файл buildozer.spec в репозитории там же и вывод buildoer в терминал (не написал здесь, потому что слишком большой):
https://github.com/Daniil1235/test-game

Comment: "fatal: целевой путь «external/jpeg» уже существует и не является пустым каталогом." Может почистить выходные каталоги попробовать? А вообще плохо, что там на русском часть путей получается, питоновские библиотеки это не любят. Может в этом ещё дело, а может и нет.